# NodeJS/Express GET exit status of external application

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I am pretty new to NodeJS and this is my first time with Express 4, I'm trying to build a simple RESTful front-end around a command-line application.  There will ultimately only be one GET and one POST necessary, with the POST handling about 3 or 4 different parameters.  The GET should call the command-line application with all default parameters, which is basically just a status check and return the exit status upon completion.  The POST will pass along POST parameters on the commandline.  I know that this basically calls for an asynchronous call, like child_process.execFile(), but I can't seem to figure out how to actually return the response from within the callback function.

This is the tutorial I used as a starting point, omitting the mongoose dependency, because I have no need for MongoDB, so I basically just followed it up to the point where you start the server.  At this point, I'm pretty lost.  I always hate writing async code...

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var child_process  = require('child_process');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port

var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});

router.get('/myapp/status', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
    child_process.execFile(
            'casperjs',
            ['myfile.js', '--cmd="Status"', '--user="myuser"', '--pass="#mypass"'],
            null,
            function(response) {
                // ???
            }, res);
});

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
router.get('/myapp/status', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.user);
   child_process.execFile(
        'casperjs',  //command
        ["myfile.js --cmd=Status --user=myuser --pass=#mypass"],  // args
        function(err, stdout, stderr) { //callback
            if (err) {
               return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            res.send(stdout);  // to send response to client
        });
});
```

Comment: But how does the anonymous callback function have any idea what res is?  I'm pretty sure I've tried a few similar ideas, and it always errored out with "res has no member function send" (or something to that effect).  Is there a way to pass a reference to res into the callback?

Comment: because of scope, parent variables are accessible in child anonymous function. I tried and it works .

Comment: Ok, well it seems like the callback is never getting called.  Just to confirm, did I get the syntax correct assuming that the external command I am invoking is

`casperjs myfile.js --cmd="Status" --user="myuser" --pass="#mypass"`

Comment: are you still facing the issue?

Comment: I'll look into it some more tomorrow and post back. I definitely appreciate the help, I just needed to walk away for the day (this is part of a larger project that has taken way more effort than it should have).

Comment: The callback is executing now, but I'm getting an almost instant response from the error handler.  The application should take about 5 seconds to complete.  The response is { "killed": false, "code": 1, "signal": null }